# 128GB MIXZA SD Card not recognized by Ubuntu

Tags: sd-card

When I plug in [this](https://www.banggood.com/Mixza-Year-of-the-Dog-Limited-Edition-U1-128GB-TF-Micro-Memory-Card-p-1324651.html) SD Card into the `Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller` SD Card reader of my laptop it does not recognize it and dmesg gives the following errors:

```
[10447.592209] mmc0: card never left busy state
[10447.592219] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[10449.788513] mmc0: problem reading SD Status register
[10451.612462] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[10453.532257] mmc0: problem reading SD Status register
```

The same SD Card works with my phone and with Windows on the same computer.

I have two 16GB SD Cards and they are both recognized by Ubuntu.

Comment: Not sure if it's the solution but... 64GB+ media usually comes formatted as exFAT, for which support must be installed in Ubuntu.